# Как хранить текстовую информацию в приложении iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, swift

Мне нужно создать приложение-справочник, которое будет содержать различные статьи, которые должны храниться  в самом приложении, а не на сервере или сайте.

Как мне хранить тексты этих статей в приложении?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) — лучший способ, [урок](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial) для Swift

Также вы можете хранить рецепты в plist-файле, [урок](http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/) для Swift

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 1):

CoreData можно использовать, но думаю это не оправдано сложно для приложения справочника.

Выбор инструмента зависит от множества факторов - какие технологии знаете умеете, в каком формате хранятся данные, это просто текст или текст с какими-то маркерами форматирования и т.д.

Посмотрите в сторону использования TextKit. [Simple Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77092/text-kit-tutorial-swift)

Если заинтересовало, то можете погуглить/купить продвинутый урок от raywenderlich, там был пример - приложение читалка, есть текстовый файл с маркерами форматирования, он читается поблочно и красиво отображается на экране.

**Update:**

Пару способов сохранять данные в приложении:

- Если логика позволяет, то можно сохранять в файл
- Использовать NSKeyedArchiver, NSKeyedUnarchiver сохранять при выходе и загружать при входе [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data)
- NSUserDefaults, думаю не совсем вам подходит
- CoreData/Realm
- Что-то кастомное, можно попробовать Parse.com  [Local Datastore](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore)

Comment: Меня интересует именно сам способ хранения текстов в приложении. Понятно, что я не могу хранить их просто строками в коде. А где у меня должны храниться эти тексты?

Comment: @yuraist подправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Текстовую информацию в приложении удобнее всего хранить в plist.
В Project Navigator кликаем правой кнопкой и выбираем NewFile -> Resourse -> Property List. В этот plist копипастим текст в том виде, который нужен для задач приложения (отдельные предложения, абзацы, страницы, главы или целую книгу). Plist позволяет обращаться к каждому разделу по пунктам (item). Как пользоваться plist - не очевидно, но есть много простых уроков.